# Tally Duplicate Name in Column

Tags: excel

I have a very simple spreadsheet with about 700-800 different lines of information, many of which are duplicates. However, I am trying to have excel count and tally the amount of times business is listed. I have seen some people use some formatting by typing the name it needs to count, but with almost 800 different names that would not make much sense. Is there a simpler way to do this?

I know Google Sheets sometimes has a chart if makes on their "Explore" tab. Something like that would be ideal to replicate.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data?

Comment: Sounds like you need a ***pivot table***

Comment: @CallumDA I thought the same thing, but when I tried it, it only deleted the duplicates and put them in order, it didn't add up how many times it was there, etc. But I have not done much work with them, so I probably did it incorrectly.

Comment: @Joe - drag the names into the rows *and* values section when creating the pivot table and it will give you a count of how many times each is in your table

Comment: @CallumDA Perfect! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments you can get something like this:
[image]

By dragging your column heading into `row` and `values` like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Say we have:

[image]

First copy column **A** to column **B** and use the RemoveDuplicates feature in the *Data* ribbon tab.

Then in **C2** enter:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,B2)
```

and copy down:

[image]